# Robotframework: Request - POST request with JSON body on demo REST site gives 400

Tags: robotframework

The 'dummy.restapiexample.com' site provides a nice demo REST service. Retrieving data is simple in Robotframework via de Request library.

Creating a body with dictionaries works! When I use JSON bodies, I get these errors.

**Test 1**: POST to reqres.in gives http status: 400

```
*** Settings ***
Library  RequestsLibrary
*** Variables ***
${RestApiB} =  https://reqres.in
*** Test Cases ***
Create a new user
    Create Session  restSession  ${RestApiB}
    ${jsonString} =  To Json  {"name":"jjxx","job":"devxx"}
    ${headers} =  Create Dictionary  Content-Type=application/json
    ${response} =  Post Request  restSession  /api/users  json=${jsonString}  headers=${headers}
    Should Be Equal As Strings  ${response.status_code}  201
```

Comment: Both of your examples work for me. Also, the title says you are getting a 406, but the body says 400. Which one are you actually getting?

Comment: Great. Please show me why your version works. AND I have changed the title. Test 1 gives a 400, test 2 gives a 406.

Comment: Maybe I copied the code wrong. The first example works for me, but after re-pasting the second example I get a 406.

Comment: What did you change so it works?

Comment: The first example I just copied verbatim, but changed `*** Keywords ***` to `*** Test Cases ***` so that it would run.

Comment: Yes, of course, Test Cases. I trimmed the file. And corrected my input. The first test case gives me 400. Which version do you have for the requests library? I have 0.4.7 for the robotframework-requests.

Comment: In the 2nd example the employee is not needed in URI it should be `/api/v1/create` but still it does not works.

Comment: I suggest use some official production ready API. The dummy API page says _There are some people are using CRON job to insert and update.Please avoid CRON job that will cause Server issue. I have changed results Data structure, I apologies for that._ and this may causing the issue while the 1st example works perfectly fine.

Comment: OK, I removed the second example. The first should work. It works with dictionaries as well. How can I pass a json body?

Comment: I have version 0.7.1 for robotframework-requests.